# Secured Mysqli Statement to avoid SQL Injection but the form sends only blank Info

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

Good day! I'm having a problem in using $stmt to avoid SQL Injection on my database. Whenever I click submit, the form only sends blank user and password but there's an multiple id that has been created. :( Is there anyone who can help me through this?

Here's my Form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
 <h1>Create Username</h1>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And my for Action is here.

```
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

//$mysqli is my connection stored at my config.php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user, password) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

// Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $password);

// Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Close the prepared statement.
$stmt->close(); 
}

if($stmt){
 echo "Data Sent";
}else{
 echo "Error in Sending";
}
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST); shows blank user and pass?

Comment: Sir @meh do you think its already secured to sql injection? I've run it now. I just created a new file for the action and everything's seems to be good now. Sir please put your "Answer" about the var_dump($_POST) how can I add it on my codes?

Comment: Just add var_dump($_POST) to the first line and update your question by getting us the output of it.

Comment: + you should ash password then send it to the database.

Comment: + do the quoting because mysqli only escapes unlike PDO that quotes the query for you. `INSERT INTO \`users\` (\`user\`, \`password\`) VALUES ('?', '?')`

Comment: Ah sir thanks! Its working now. Thanks a lot for the tip. Sir, but the way, How can I convert it to "Select" query. using those statement above?

Comment: Example, in Login page. How can I select the column credentials of username and password using $stmt?

Comment: I told you in the answer. Let me know if it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli doesn't quote like PDO. Do it manually.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `password`) VALUES ('?', '?')
```

For validating user, if you are using password_hash() and password_verify() functions of php select them first and check password.

If you're using md5, sha1, ... first md5 the input password from post, then

```
 select * from `users` where `username`= '...' AND `password` = 'Here it should be the hashed pw';
```